# Lucene QueryParser code upgrade to Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

In order to convert Lucene code to Solr, what is the proper way to convert Query Parser? What's the best way to replicate the same functionality in Solr?

Comment: I don't think you need to make changes in Query Parser though but you can quickly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892096/sitecore-8-1-steps-for-converting-the-lucene-search-to-solr this article

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, I want to get rid of all Lucene library in solution and make it very generic

Comment: It's hard to say how to convert your code without.. your code. Can you be a bit more specific? Normally you use the Sitecore (search) API to make it generic.